# Designing a SQL Server database to be used in a shared hosting environment

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, shared-hosting

I've always personally used dedicated servers and VPS so I have full control over my SQL Server (using 2008 R2). Now I'm working on a asp.net project that could be deployed in a shared hosting environment which I have little experience with. My question is are there limitations on the features of SQL Server I can use in a shared environment?

For example, if I design my database to use views, stored procedures, user defined functions and triggers, will my end user be able to use them in shared hosting? Do hosts typically provide access to these and are they difficult to use?

If so, I assume the host will give a user his login, and he can use tools like management studios to operate within his own DB as if it were his own server? If I provide scripts to install these, will they run on the user's credential within his database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All database objects are available. It includes tables, views, sp, functions, keys, certificates...

Usually CLR and FTS are disabled.

At last, you will not be able to access most of the server objects (logins, server trigger, backup devices, linked servers etc...)

SQL Mail, Reporting Services are often turned off too.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how the other users are authenticated to the database, if it is one shared database for all users.

If every user on the host will recieve it's own db:
If your scripts are written in a generic way (are not bound to fixed usernames in that case for example), other users will be able to execute them on their database and will have the same functionality. (Secondary click on the db and choose task->backup for example)

You could also provide simple pure backup dumps of a freshly setup database so for other users, the setup is only one click away. Also from the beginning, you should think about how to roll out changes that need to affect every user. 
One possible approach is to always supply delta scripts, no matter if you are patching errors away or adding new things.

Comment: What about the features of the database (stored procedures, UDF, triggers etc)? Typically, are they fully supported in a shared hosting environment?

Comment: @user683202
: 99.9% Yes. why wouldn't they be? check with your intended provider.